# Ubuntu dual boot booting into windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed ubuntu 18.04 to dual boot alongside windows, i made a root partition, a swap partition and an efi partition. I have fast boot and secure boot disabled, ubuntu is #1 in the bios boot manager, even if i hold f12 during startup and manually choose to boot into ubuntu the pc just doesn't care and boots into windows 10. Any help? This is the video: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/drpq7r/i_tried_dual_booting_ubuntu_alongside_windows_to/

Comment: Please confirm your BIOS is configured with Legacy Boot disabled, CM Support disabled (if there is one in your BIOS), and Windows 8/10 Features disabled (if there is one in your BIOS). NOTE: Ever since late 2017, a Swap File in the same partition as root or home is preferred by Ubuntu's installation program. Before then, the Linux kernel has performance issues with swap files, but that was resolved > 2 years ago. If you will not use Hibernation in Ubuntu, you do not need a Swap Partition.

Comment: Need more info. To start with, boot into Live Ubuntu, run command `sudo parted -l` and paste output into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try spamming <kbd>Shift</kbd> until you see GRUB is loading and then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> until the GRUB menu loads. You also may want to spam your <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.